# Can a spaceship land on a strongly magnetic planet?

Tags: magnetic-field

What would happen to a spaceship if it tried to land on a planet that had a magnetic field as strong as Jupiter's?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because a hypothetical ship landing on a hypothetical magnetic planet is not related to space exploration.

Comment: It is related to hypothetical space exploration, which is a subset of space exploration. Keep open.

Comment: It would land. Approaching a magnetar, a neutron star with an enormous magnetic field, might however dissolve not only all electronics but all chemistry, as electrons abandon their natural atomic orbitals and disconnect from molecular relations. That's how I imagine it anyway.

Comment: How much strong are we talking about? A little more than Earth? Sounds easy. So strong that all electronics go crazy and all dipoles undergo torques higher than the ones consider in any Earth-orbiting project? Maybe could be worked out. So strong that computers stop working? This becomes speculation.